# How to change default object field size?

Tags: custom-field, fields, app

I've created new `App` called `Library` with Books objects.

I have very long book name. After type in this long title into `Book Name` field and click Save button i have following:

```
        Data Storage Limits Exceeded
    Your company currently has exceeded its data storage limits
 including an extra overflow buffer. Per our terms and conditions,
 we cannot permit additional data creation within our system until
 your company first reduces its current data storage.
 Please contact your company's salesforce.com administrator to resolve this.
 We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.
```

Is it possible to increase field size with simple name and not to contact the administrator?

Comment: This problem is not from the field. It looks like organization data storage is not sufficient. If the same name is entered in some org where data storage limit is larger, you would not get the error.

Comment: It says data storage limit exceeded, so check if your allocated data size is being exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with the data you are trying to save. Go try to save a record of *any* type, and you will see the same error.

When you go over the limit of storage usage for your organization, you're blocked from creating any new data. You have two basic approaches to resolve this issue, though it's likely only the former is tenable as a long-term strategy:

1. **Aggressively remove unused data**

   It is likely that you have data in your org which hasn't been looked at for months/years. You might even have entire objects which are obsolete but were never removed. See what you can trim down.
2. **Petition support to increase your storage usage limit**

   I have heard of it being a limit on which Salesforce can be a bit more lenient (for a cost) but never tried to acquire more storage myself.